# How to read/parse Array in form-data node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image: This is how I want to send data]

Please check the above image, I am trying to read this in Node Js. I am using express js and have tried debugging `req.body`. It is returning an empty object  `{}`.

I am using `app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));` . To read body but unable to read the data.
I can parse/read json object which are sent in raw(json) format

Edit:

Added multer

But Still Return empty object `{}`

```
router.post('/array', uploads.none(), (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`bodyParser.json` is used to parse `application/json` content type. The solution is to use `multer` middleware to parse `form-data` content type.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Added multer

But Still Return empty object {}

 ` router.post('/array', uploads.none(), (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body) // returns empty object
}) `